# How can I do a conditional statement so ajax fetchs the correct xml document

Tags: javascript, ajax, conditional-statements

I have a simple code to fetch a xml file and display it as a drop down list. However, I would like to fetch the xml file according to a condition. If it equals to study1 then .ajax selects ctc3.xml, else it selects ctc5.xml.

My code was working fine if I was fetching a specific xml file, but the conditional does not work.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script lang="Javascript"> $.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var myField = $("#myList") var myOutputField = $("#myOutput").parent().parent().find("input");
    myOutputField.attr("readonly",true);
    var studyID="${studyName}";
    if (studyID!="Test"){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "includes/ctcae3.xml", 
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: parseXML 
    });
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET", 
            url: "includes/ctcae5.xml", 
            dataType: "xml", 
            success: parseXML 
        });
    }
    function parseXML(xml){
        $(xml).find("atccode").each(function(){
            myField.append($("<option />").val($(this).attr("code")).text($(this).find("description").text()));
        }); 
        myField.val(myOutputField.val());
    } 
    myField.change(function(){
        myOutputField.val(myField.val());
        myOutputField.change();
    });
 });
 </script><select id="myList"> <option val="None"/>None </select> `
```

Comment: Your conditional is checking if `"${studyName}" == 'Test'` which will always fail.

Comment: Sorry, corrected conditional to 'if (studyID!="Test")' still doesn't work tho.

Comment: Well, have you debugged into your code and asked yourself if this test is correct, and the conditions are changing as expected? SO is a terrible debugger... https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Using the inspect  feature from Chrome, I can see the value of the studyID variable and it matches the value "Test", which should make ajax choose the ctcae5.xml file. But instead, the drop down list shows as empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved. Clearly my brain was already fried. It was just a matter of adding the ';' to `var myField = $("#myList");`